# Rediect url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have been trying to redirect my below url

```
http://example.com/En/product_de.php?123
```

to

```
http://example.com/En/products/123
```

here is my htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^/?product_de\.php$ http://example.com/En/products/%1 [L,R=301]
```

What I am doing wrong kindly help me

Answer (score 0):

In directory-context, `RewriteRule`'s first argument is relative to the directory. Things in a .htaccess file are in the directory-context of the directory the .htaccess file is in.

In a .htaccess file, the first argument of `RewriteRule` never starts with a slash. I assume you have your .htaccess file in your http root. Your rule should therefore be:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^En/product_de\.php /En/products/%1? [L,R]
```

Change the `[R]` flag to `[R=301]` when everything works as expected.

Comment: I've just tried the same thing to see if it works, but the problem is that the OP is checking for `?id=number` but is actually submitting `?number`, which is why it doesn't do anything. Also, the query string should be discarded, should it not? `RewriteRule ^En/product_de\.php /En/products/%1? [L,R]`

Comment: You are right about the second thing. I suspect OP just typoed about the id, because I can't see anyone match on id=something if you don't have an id in your url.